# How to obtain the original user name in a command prompt started by runas

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, runas

I use `runas /user:abc cmd` to start a command prompt. After login, I will run a vbs script.

The login abc has special file/folder permission, and it is the main reason for using runas. Otherwise the vbs script will not work due to lack of permission

Inside this command prompt session, how can I obtain the username which started the runas command? I want to log this information inside my vbs script.

As an example, let's say my id is 'akong'. After I started command prompt as 'abc' with runas, I want to be able print out 'akong' one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you would need to send this information in to the script.

example:

runas /user:abc program.exe %username%

I'm guessing that the env will get expanded before the command is processed.. but I have no way of verifying that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you dont use /noprofile as a switch for runas, user abc's profile will load.
You can simply type

> whoami

at the command line and it will return domainname\abc

or from in the VBScript:

> Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
>
> strInfo = "User Name is     " & objNet.UserName & vbCRLF & _
>             "Computer Name is " & objNet.ComputerName & vbCRLF & _
>             "Domain Name is   " & objNet.UserDomain
>
> MsgBox strInfo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have clarified my question by adding an example. I actually want to print my original id, not the runas id 'abc'. Whoami prints 'abc' regardless /noprofile is used or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginning to think it's not possible to get the original user's name.  At the commandline I tried

```
Set
```

It lists all the 'abc' user details and none of the 'akong' user.